# Not able to access JSP from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I have a simple project in springboot and facing with issue with JSP. I am getting

> Whitelabel Error Page

error as below  :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   /webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp

Please help me with this.

Below is my project structure.

[image]

Below is my POM:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>SpringBootHelloWorld</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Below is application.properties :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanagement
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Code of Controller :

```
package com.boot.controller;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/hu")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world:";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/hu1")
    public ModelAndView hello1(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //return "hello world1:";
        String msg="hello";
        return new ModelAndView("login", "msg", msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the prefix to `WEB-INF/jsp/`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=WEB-INF/jsp/
```